# Customize "Additional Information Required" Email

Tags: 2010, email, alert, content-organizer

We are using the Content Organizer in SharePoint 2010 to route documents to a central location. Before the documents are routed, however, there are a few required meta-data fields that need to be filled out. If the user does not fill out the meta-data fields completely, the items sit in the drop-off library and the user gets the following email each day:

> **Subject:** *Site Name* - Additional Information Required
>
> **Message:** You recently submitted documents to *Site Name*. Additional information is     required to complete the submission. Follow the link below to enter the required     information.
>
> To see the list of documents that could not be routed: *Site URL*

Is there any way to customize the contents, subject, or sender on these emails? As far as I can tell its not part of the Predefined Alert Templates outlined [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb802738%28v=office.14%29.aspx). Is there any way to customize this alert aside from doing some trickery at the Exchange level?

Thanks much.